# TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function with Handsontable and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am getting a couple of errors when using Handsontable with jQuery and React. I am catching a

```
TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function
```

And in the console I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined
```

thrown by onMouseMove.

I am setting up handsontable like this:

```
import Handsontable from 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full';
const $ = require('jquery');

function createTable(data){
    const container = $(myContainer);
    const hotContainer = container.find('.myTable');
    console.log(hotContainer);
    const datatable = Handsontable(hotContainer, {
    colHeaders: true,
    });
    datatable.loadData(data.records);
}
module.exports = createTable;
```

console.log(hotContainer) returns Object so it exists.

Any ideas on what I may be doing incorrectly or not doing?

Comment: Where are you writing `t.addEventListener`? Full code would be nice.

Comment: @figgycity50 I added a bit more code to help explain, bit hard to put a complete example and app is huge and I am a react/js beginner. I dont call t.addEventListener anywhere, it must be called by handsontable. I think the problem is something is being called by handsontable that doesnt exist at time of cll.